# モジュールをインポートしようとすると構文エラーになる

Tags: python, python3, google-colaboratory

株の本にかいてあることを試しているのですが、こんな構文はないと言われました。
5行目が違うそうです。

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta
import relativedelta
import polotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objects as go
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']= [24,8]
```

Answer (score 3):

改行しないで1行で。

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```